# Array repeating the value

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have this function that verifies every element that has the initial id "zoom_grupo_documento___", take it's value and add (push) to an array.
But beacause I'm using the each jquery function it keeps repeating the array that already been added.

```
function setSelectedZoomItem() {
  $("[id^=zoom_grupo_documento___]").each(function () {
    var grupo = $(this).val();

    if (grupo != '' && grupo != undefined && grupo != null) {
      // $("#checkbox_nota_fiscal").prop("checked", true);
      arrayCheckList.push(grupo)
    }

    // console.log('grupo do change -> ' + grupo)
    console.log(arrayCheckList)
  })
}
```

Comment: what does not work?

Comment: Beacause it takes the previous element that already been added and reinsert it

Comment: Shouldn't you had to use in your if-conditions `&&` instead of `||` ?

Answer (score 0):

You could check the value and array in advance.

```
if (grupo && !arrayCheckList.includes(grupo)) {
    arrayCheckList.push(grupo);
}
```